# Oracle SQL UPDATE SELECT with JOIN got error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

Here is my SQL Query

```
UPDATE
(SELECT
    *
FROM
    web_fe_ipo_ipo_application   apps
    INNER JOIN web_fe_ipo_ipo_entry ipo ON apps.ipo_link_id = ipo.ipo_ref_number
WHERE
    ( ( apps.status = 0
        OR ( apps.status = 2
             AND apps.sub_status = 0
             AND ipo.enable_omnibus_account = 1 ) )
      AND ( apps.applied_qty BETWEEN 1 AND 10 )
      AND apps.ipo_link_id = '984'
      AND apps.latest = 1
      AND ipo.latest = 1
      AND apps.tranche_name = 'Public-1' )
ORDER BY
    ipo_random(50)
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY) selection 
SET selection.initial_allot_qty = 5;
```

but it was not working well

I need to select random data from table then update after execute this query I got bellow error

```
Error at Command Line : 20 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
01733. 00000 -  "virtual column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Oracle is not very flexible about using join's in updates.  You might want to consider `merge` instead.

Comment: can I update it after select random rows using `merge` ?

Comment: . . If your table has a primary key, that should not be a problem.

Comment: if you konw could you please write a answer; and it will great help to me

Answer (score 1):

Use a MERGE statement.

Here is an example:

```
MERGE INTO workers e
USING data_works h -- You can use the SELECT statement as well.
ON (e.f_id= h.f_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET e.address= h.address
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (f_id, address)
VALUES (h.f_id, h.address);
```

Here is your code. Hope it will work.

```
    MERGE INTO web_fe_ipo_ipo_application apps
 USING (SELECT * FROM web_fe_ipo_ipo_entry  ipo ORDER BY
    ipo_random)
 ON(apps.ipo_link_id = ipo.ipo_ref_number)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET apps.initial_allot_qty = 5
WHERE apps.status = 0
        OR(apps.status = 2
             AND apps.sub_status = 0
             AND ipo.enable_omnibus_account = 1) 
      AND apps.applied_qty BETWEEN 1 AND 10 
      AND apps.ipo_link_id = '984'
      AND apps.latest = 1
      AND ipo.latest = 1
      AND apps.tranche_name = 'Public-1'
      AND rownum <=5;
```

Use the MERGE statement to select rows from one or more sources for INSERT or UPDATE operations in a table or view.

You can specify conditions to determine whether the target table or view is updated.

Merge operation is a convenient way to combine multiple operations. It allows you to avoid multiple INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE DML statements as well.

Comment: Can you put the answer similer with my code because there have `ORDER BY` and `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 2
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: I did some changes on the query. Could you please try again?